# How to run chrome in non headless mode in heroku free dyno

Tags: google-chrome, heroku, headless

Is there a way to run the chrome browser in the non headless mode in Heroku app.In default the Build packs are in the headless mode. But for my code i want the chrome browser to open so that user can scan the qr code for whats app functionality.Can someone help me..

Comment: Why don't you serve the QR code over a webserver? You don't have access to a Heroku server. You can't make a SSH connection. You cannot make a RDP/VNC connection. If the Heroku server came with a Desktop you wouldn't be able to see its screen.

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Chrome running on the server will _never_ show up on the user's machine. (There would be no point, but if you managed to run it with a GUI, that GUI would pop up on a server in some Amazon datacentre.) Maybe you're confused because your development server and your development client are on the same machine?

Comment: I am surprised so many people viewed this question but no one knows the answer!!